# How to set colormap midpoint in holoviews heatmap

Tags: holoviews, pyviz

I'm plotting a heatmap with holoviews using the Plotly backend.

```
import holoviews as hv

hv.HeatMap([(0,0,-10),(0,1,-9),(1,0,0),(1,1,2)]).opts(cmap="RdBu")
```

I'd like to set the colormap midpoint to 0 to make the diverging colormap meaningful. In plotly I would do `color_continuous_midpoint=0` for the `px.imshow` function of plotly express.

How can I set the colormap midpoint in holoviews?

Does Holoviews use `px.imshow`? If so, is there a way to pass through this (or any) raw parameters? How can I find the solution in the documentation of Holoviews? I tried, but failed to find a hint.

Comment: HoloViews is built on Plotly, not Plotly Express; its Plotly support predated Plotly Express. I'm not aware of any convenient way to set the midpoint, so that would be a good feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the midpoint indirectly by specifying the limits of the colormap via the `clim` parameter. E.g. the following has a midpoint of 0:

```
hm = hv.HeatMap(data)
hm.opts(colorbar=True, cmap="coolwarm_r", clim=(-30, 30))
```

From the docs:

> clim:              User-specified colorbar axis range limits for the
> plot, as a tuple (low,high).
> If specified, takes precedence over data and dimension ranges.

Also check out the `clim_percentile` parameter:

> clim_percentile:   Percentile value to compute colorscale robust to outliers. If
> True, uses 2nd and 98th percentile; otherwise uses the specified
> numerical percentile value.